# how to get data from multiples functions in oracle db through cx_oracle/python script

Tags: python, oracle, oracle10g, cx-oracle

so I have a few functions(6) in a big query, that alone works  but when I try to execute in a python script and add the implicit statement it doesn't, it shows the error:

-"PLS-00382 expression is of wrong type  ORA-06550"

-"PL/SQL: Statement ignored"

-"PLS-00302: component 'RETURN_RESULT' must be declared".

the query is vagely something like this:

```
DECLARE

   x SYS_REFCURSOR; -- error

   little_date1 DATE;
   little_date2 DATE;
   big_date DATE;

FUNCTION fun(little_date1)
 RETURN
 ...
BEGIN 
  SELECT ...
  RETURN little_date2 
END;
FUNCTION fun2(little_date2)
 RETURN
 ...
BEGIN 
  SELECT ...
  RETURN big_date;
END;
x:= big_date
dbms_sql.RETURN_RESULT(x); --error
```

if I execute the query in dbeaver it works until I add the "SYS_REFCURSOR" and the "dbms_sql.RETURN_RESULT".

in python is just a simple print, but doesn't reach that part:

```
for results in cur.getimplicitresults():
   for r in results
      print (r)
```

may be the oracle version? it's Oracle 10g and in that case could you give me some pointers? not doo the job, just some compass help.
I have to split the query to make it work?
its my first job as a developer I don't want to messed up. Ive done similar things in SQL, but not in Oracle even less with cx_Oracle.

Comment: `x` is of type `sys_refcursor` - something that may produce a set of rows and that may be fetched. `big_date` is of type `date` - a scalar binary value representing a datetime. You cannot assign one of them to the other, it doesn't make any sense. Please describe what do you want to achieve. The code works until you assign a date value to cursor because without this it does exactly nothing (though, it should throw an error that cursor is not opened)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle introduced the `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` function in Oracle 12. You cannot use it in Oracle 10.

Use a [bind variable `:something` to get the output](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#bind-direction):

```sql
DECLARE
  FUNCTION fun(p_date IN DATE)
  RETURN DATE
  IS
  BEGIN 
    RETURN p_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
  END;

  FUNCTION fun2(p_date IN DATE)
  RETURN DATE
  IS
  BEGIN 
    RETURN p_date + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE;
  END;
BEGIN
  :value := fun2( fun( SYSDATE ) );
END;
/
```